# Does Laravel Livewire dispatch js events when change some property?

Tags: javascript, laravel, dom-events, laravel-livewire

I have a question about [laravel livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/), when I change some property of my component, the front input binded to that property emits some event?

```php
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $this->post = $post;
    $this->start_date = $post->start_date;
}
```

I was thinking livewire dispatch the same event used to listen the front:

```html
<input wire:model="start_date" type="date" id="dateId" />

<script wire:ignore>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {

        $("#dateId").on('input', (event) => {
             console.log(345);
        });

    });
</script>
```

But nothing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation for livewire 2.x](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks#js-hooks), what you're looking could be one of these hooks. Maybe component.initialized, element.updating, element.updated or one of the messages.

| Hooks | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `component.initialized` | Called when a component has been initialized on the page by Livewire |
| `element.initialized` | Called when Livewire initializes an individual element |
| `element.updating` | Called before Livewire updates an element during its DOM-diffing cycle after a network roundtrip |
| `element.updated` | Called after Livewire updates an element during its DOM-diffing cycle after a network roundtrip |
| `element.removed` | Called after Livewire removes an element during its DOM-diffing cycle |
| `message.sent` | Called when a Livewire update triggers a message sent to the server via AJAX |
| `message.failed` | Called if the message send fails for some reason |
| `message.received` | Called when a message has finished its roudtrip, but before Livewire updates the DOM |
| `message.processed` | Called after Livewire processes all side effects (including DOM-diffing) from a message |

```xml
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        Livewire.hook('component.initialized', (component) => {})
        Livewire.hook('element.initialized', (el, component) => {})
        Livewire.hook('element.updating', (fromEl, toEl, component) => {})
        Livewire.hook('element.updated', (el, component) => {})
        Livewire.hook('element.removed', (el, component) => {})
        Livewire.hook('message.sent', (message, component) => {})
        Livewire.hook('message.failed', (message, component) => {})
        Livewire.hook('message.received', (message, component) => {})
        Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {})
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not immediately when you change a property inside PHP Livewire component the way you showed.

You would need to emit a browser event from Livewire Component and listen for it in the frontend as described in [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#browser).

You can also try [Global Livewire JavaScript Object](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/reference#global-livewire-js): `Livewire.on(eventName, (...params) => {})`

But the easiest way to interact with Livewire is probably with [Alpine.js](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js).